# InvalidCastException in ComboBox SelectionChanged event handler

Tags: wpf, autocad

This code works well:

```
 private void Combobox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var combo = (ComboBox)sender;
     var pointGroupList = (List<PointGroup>)combo.ItemsSource;
     combo.ItemsSource = pointGroupList.Select(group => group.Name);
 }
```

But this one doesn't work at all:

```
private void Combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var combo = (ComboBox)sender;
    var pointGroupList = (List<PointGroup>)combo.ItemsSource;
    textBlock1.Text = "num of points:" + pointGroupList.Find(group => group.Name == (string)combo.SelectedItem).PointsCount.ToString();
}
```

Here's the message in my output window:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator2[Autodesk.Civil.DatabaseServices.PointGroup,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Autodesk.Civil.DatabaseServices.PointGroup]'. at _01_COGO_Points.ModalDialog_1.Combobox1_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) in D:\00 Materials\c3d\c#\examples\ACAD\01 COGO Points\Window.xaml.cs:line 49

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the error System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[Autodesk.Civil.DatabaseServices.PointGroup,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Autodesk.Civil.DatabaseServices.PointGroup]'.
   at _01_COGO_Points.ModalDialog_1.Combobox1_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) in D:\00 Materials\c3d\c#\examples\ACAD\01 COGO Points\Window.xaml.cs:line 49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing in your `Loaded` event is quite weird. I would not recommend doing that, as it will wreck your bindings. If the reason you're doing that is so that the `Name` property is shown in your `ComboBox`, you should rather use a `DataTemplate`. Something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="pntGroupTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ac:PointGroup}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and you will of course need to add a namespace to your Window. Something like this:

```
xmlns:ac="clr-namespace:Autodesk.Civil.DatabaseServices;assembly=AeccDbMgd"
```

I don't have Civil, so not sure if that's exactly right, but it should be close. Intellisense should be able to help you with the correct path if this one is not quite right.

and in your combobox,

```
<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pntGroupTemplate}" ...  />
```

My best advice is to just completely get rid of all the code in your `Combobox1_Loaded` event handler and create a `DataTemplate` in xaml to display the `Name` property using the code snippet above. And lastly, change your lambda expression from this:

```
group => group.Name == (string)combo.SelectedItem
```

to this:

```
group => group.Name == (combo.SelectedItem as PointGroup)?.Name
```

The exception you're getting is due to the second line. When you call the `Select` method in the Loaded event, it returns `IEnumerable<string>`, so when you're casting the `ItemsSource` to `List<PointGroup>` that's where everything goes sideways in so many different ways :-).

Another issue with what you're doing, is that now, `SelectedItem` is a `string`, and does not have a `Name` property.

Hope that helps

Comment: the namespace prefix ac is not defined (error maassage)

Comment: you need to add the namespace to your Window somethign like `xmlns:ac="clr-namespace:Autodesk.Civil.DatabaseServices;assembly=AeccDbMgd"`. I don't have Civil, so not sure if that's exactly right, but it should be close. Intellisense should be able to help you with the correct path.

Comment: Added it to the answer.